# Waba Whatsapp flow dynamic date picker? Unavailable date dynamic?

Tags: forms, whatsapp, whatsapp-flows

I am trying to use WhatsApp flow, wondering if is there any way we can set unavailable date dynamic in WhatsApp form?

> {
> "type": "DatePicker",
> "name": "date",
> "label": "The Appointment Date",
> "min-date": "1693569600000",
> "max-date": "1767182400000",
> "required": true,
> "unavailable-dates": [
> "1694779200000",
> "1697371200000"
> ]
> }

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of Flow https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/flows/reference/flowjson/components#dp

We can have dynamic unavailable dates.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use unavailable dates dynamically. You just need to define dynamic dates in data, and then you have to provide with data_exchange while communicate with server.

Hope it helps!

need more help, Always welcome.